# Admin panel Products Save and Stay not working properly in google chrome browser (Version 62.0.3202.62) - Prestashop 1.6.1.3

Tags: php, google-chrome, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to edit product information from `prestashop` admin panel. Unfortunately, I can't able to save my changes in first attempt itself. It takes 2 to 3 attempts `save and stay` action to work.

My google chrome browser version is 62.0.3202.62. But in all other browsers working first attempt itself. I can't able to find out solution. Any help/hint on this greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searched lot of resources but none of solutions found. Finally by commenting the following code was solved my issue,

**File Path:**

```
admin/themes/default/template/controllers/products/helpers/form/form.tpl
```

**Code to comment:** In product_form validate comment below code

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
},
```

But this may not be a good solution. Any good solutions are mostly welcome!

Comment: Provide more information about the submit function on your machine, check console on the browser you have problem on